# add identifier to segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have created a segue from a button, but it has given me the following error. I am using Swift and Xcode 6.

```
/Users/dave_cooljamdesign/Desktop/XcodeDev/findaphysio2/FindaPhysio/FindaPhysio/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier
```

How do I give them an identifier when I'm draging from table view to the detail view?

Below is some code to show what I am doing in the view controller

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ClinicsTableViewController:
UITableViewController {
var clinic = [Clinics]()

@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    self.clinic = [Clinics(name:"Chocolate")]

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.clinic.count
}

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      //ask for a reusable cell from the tableview, the tableview will create a new one if it doesn't have any
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("findaphysioCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Get the corresponding candy from our candies array
    let _clinic = self.clinic[indexPath.row]

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel!.text = _clinic.name 
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: select the segue in storyboard and command + option + 4.

Answer (score 1):

Find the segue on the storyboard (the line between view controllers with a circle in the middle) and click it.

[image]

Then open the attributes inspector in the utilities pane and give it an identifier.

[image]

As gabbler mentioned, the shortcut <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> will immediately open the attributes inspector.

Comment: I must admit im loving swift i was put off by objective c but doing an app for a customer in swift and turning out allot easier to understand

Comment: i have named it connor then it comes up with the following error when i click on the button
* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FindaPhysio.ClinicsTableViewController 0x79f421a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mapView.'

Comment: @DavidBuckley that error doesn't seem to related to related to this issue, so it's better as a separate question

Comment: It's likely caused by an outlet that you haven't properly connected. Did you connect an outlet mapview then delete it from your code file?

Comment: think thats the answer will try now

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, select the segue between the two view controllers. Go to the attributes inspector on the right and add an identifier name.

In your code do something like this:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("setupView", sender: self)
```

Obviously change 'setupView' with whatever you set for the segue identifier.